# Error while writing Spark DF to parquet (Parquet column cannot be converted. Column: [word_c], Expected: StringType, Found: INT64

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake

I have a couple of parquet files spread across different folders and I'm using following command to read them into a Spark DF on Databricks:

```
df = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").schema(parquet_schema).parquet('/mnt/my_blobstorage/snap/*/*.parquet')
```

My parquet schema contains only StringType. Then I diplay the Dataframe and additionally I do a PrintSchema to make sure that all the columns are of StringType.
When I try to write this DF back to my Blob Storage, by using this command:

```
df.write.parquet('/mnt/my_blobstorage/saved/merged_df.parquet')
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Parquet column cannot be converted. Column: [word_c], Expected: StringType, Found: INT64
```

I have tried all the solutions that I founf on StackOverflow and nothing worked so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Well I suppose that schema from one or more source parquet files doesn't parquet_schema you provided. I would suggest you to omit schema(parquet_schema) part and print schema from that load. Parquet files are self contained, so they contains schema definitions inside them. You don't need to provide schema on your own, and if you do that schema must be same as schema inside parquet files.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the above scenario and got same error even though `printSchema` gave the correct schema.

[image]

I agree with **@partlov** that here the dataframe took the schema from the parquet files and thats the reason for the error.

**In this case**, you can try the below workaround to resolve the error.

First read the parquet files without giving your schema. After that convert the column type to String using below code. Now, you can write this to your final parquet file.

```
df3 = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet('/mnt/mountdata/snap/*/*.parquet')
df3.printSchema()

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
for i in df3.dtypes:
    if i[1]!="string":
        df3=df3.withColumn(i[0],col(i[0]).cast(StringType()))
        print("done for column : ",i[0])
print("dataframe with required schema : ")
df3.printSchema()
display(df3)
```

**My Execution:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the proposed solution. Unfortunately when I read the parquet files without giving my schema, I am getting the following error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed merging schema

Comment: For merging, your two parquet should have same schema. Please check that and try again.